# Prime icons not appearing in IE11

Tags: angular6, primeng

I am working on angular 6 and I am using prime NG framework, which has components like growl messages used to display pop-up messages in my application. The Prime icons in growl messages are appearing in chrome, but not in IE11 (IE v11.2248.14393.0) in Windows 10. They are, however, appearing in IE11 in Windows 8 (IE v11.0.9600.18953). Please find the relevant code excerpt below:

primeiconstest.component.ts

```
showSuccess(message) {
    this.msgs = [];
    this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: message });
}
showError(details) {
    this.msgs = [];
    this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: details });
}

saveMultipleRowsData(data) {
    // this.spinner.show();
    this.customerTypeDataService.postData(data).subscribe(
        response => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.disabledFlagList.length; i++) {
                if (!this.disabledFlagList[i].disabled) {
                    this.disabledFlagList[i].disabled = true;
                    this.disabledFlagList[i].added = false;
                }
            }
   this.customerTypeData = response;
            // this.spinner.hide();
            this.showSuccess(this.globalServiceData.dynamicErrorMessages['multipleRowMessage.save.success']);
        },
        error => {
            // this.spinner.hide();
            this.showError(error.error.details[0]);
        }
    );
}
```

primeiconstest.component.html

```
 <p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog>
<p-growl [life] = 5000 [(value)]="msgs" [style]="{'top': '110px'}"></p-growl>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can add your code in the question it will be easy for us to understand your problem and to give you a quick and a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Primeng is a fabulous front end framework designed for the modern browsers like chrome, firefox, etc.. Sometimes IE11 is not compiling all syntax (Assuming it ES6)  syntax. In windows 10 you can set the IE - Edge browser when opening the application

To do that in your index.html

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

In your poyfills.ts file: Include the following script:

```
    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Add the following tag and give a try.

Hope it should work.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is with the primeicons not getting displayed in IE11

Comment: would be great if you can post your code in stackblitz or plunker. So that I can run it and provide the proper solution

Comment: Try the hard refresh in your windows 10 by pressing ctrl+f5. It works for me. Remember you need to update all the window patches

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you please try and let me know

Comment: In polyfills.ts, its already there and yet its not working. Can you suggest some solution like how to embed the font formats to internet explorer 11?i face issues with font styles like "primeicons" and "roboto"